# The use of "since" in “The Empire had long since fallen to the Barbarians”

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, grammaticality, word-in-context

> Although Justinian’s reign started inauspiciously, he still enjoyed astonishing success. **Rome and Western Empire had long since fallen to the Barbarians**. But he and Theodora set out to recover the lost territories of Roman Empire.

To me, the it might be *Rome and Western Empire had long been fallen to the Barbarians*. Why is there a *since*? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long%20since

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've actually done two things in your rewrite, which makes this a very interesting question. It's grammatically fine to simply delete "since":

> Rome and the western empire had long fallen to the barbarians.

The word *since* in the original sort of just works as a reminder that we're talking about the time when Rome fell *relative* to the time when Justinian started his reign. That idea can be understood without *since*, but *since* is adding a sort of emphasis.

However, you *also replaced* since with *been*. That actually changes the idea of the verb from simply the past perfect of "fall" to the idea of "to be fallen." In English, you can say "I fell from glory," or "I am fallen from glory." They mean roughly the same thing, although the second one focuses more on the state of being fallen, rather than the action of falling. It also has somewhat religious, shameful, or tragic overtones. I'd say that the author possibly wanted to simply state the fact that they *had fallen*, without giving it the sort of moral or poetic overtones it would have if the author said they *had been fallen*.